# Proving if $\frac{3x+1}{x-1}$ is onto?

Tags: functions, proof-writing

So, I have this function: $f(x)=\frac{3x+1}{x-1}$.

So, in proving if it is onto, then by definition, for every b in B, there exists an a in A such that $f(a)=b$. So, let's solve or a.

We get: $b=\frac{3a+1}{a-1}$, $b(a-1)=3a+1$, $3a-b(a-1)=-1$, $(3a-ba)-b=-1$,$a(3-b)-b=-1$, $a(3-b)=b-1$, $a=\frac{b-1}{3-b}$.

So, as I see it, b is undefined for -3 and 3, and therefore, the function cannot be onto.

Is this correct? Usually when I do these problems, it's always the variable minus of plus a number (eg. $\frac{x+1}{x-5}$, where it is undefined for 5.)

Comment: What are $A,B$ to begin with?

Comment: A = $\mathrm R-{1}$, and B=$\mathrm R$. My apologies for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop at the step before the last. You proved that 
$$
f(a) = b \iff a(3-b) = b-1
$$

As a consequence:

1. if $b\neq 3$, there is a solution (obtained with the division)
2. if $b=3$ this is equivalent to
   $$
   0 = 2
   $$which is always false. Hence there is no solution and the function is not onto on $\Bbb R$ (but onto $\Bbb R - \{3\}$)

Do not divide by 0!